# power expansion of $\frac{z}{z^{4} +9}$

Tags: complex-analysis

The next question in John D'Angelo's text that I'm stuck on is Exercise 4.7:

Find the power series expansion for $\frac{z}{z^{4} +9}$  about 0. Where does it converge ?

I understand this section in the text better now based on previous explanations from this list so even just a hint is appreciated.  Again, its' not homework. Just a stat person trying to learn the basics of complex analysis. Thanks.

Comment: Can you see a geometric series in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $|z|<\sqrt{3}$,
$$\frac{z}{z^4+9}=\frac{z/9}{1+z^4/9}=\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^j}{3^{2j+2}}z^{4j+1}.$$

Comment: thanks all. I get the trick now that the series needs to be transformed into a geometric series.it's much appreciated. i'm checking the last one because that one showed all the steps. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

> $$ \frac{z}{9}(1+\frac{z^4}{9})^{-1}=\dots  $$